# What are the different types of props can be send from one component to the other using properties in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, react-props, react-proptypes

I have been using React for an year now. I have experienced sending below few types of props from one component to the other.

I have component A & B. Here component A is a parent of B. I send some props from A to B like string, number, Boolean, array, object and function.

**Component A:**

```
class A extends Component {
   render(){
       return(
            <div>
                 <B string="String Prop" number={123} Boolean={true} array=[] Object={} function={this.function} />
            </div>
       );
   }
}
```

My query is, is there any other types of properties can be send to a component apart from what I have mentioned?

Comment: quick read, should answer your query - https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've just structured this question in a way that makes it a little difficult to understand but with React, you can send any complex object via the props.

Prop types are simply there as a way to strongly type what you expect to be passed down.

Check out the docs to see all the accepted prop types for React:

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Taking specific note of the fact you can both create your own custom validator, or even set it to "any" which means it doesn't care what the type is as long as it's there:

```
// A value of any data type
  requiredAny: PropTypes.any.isRequired,

  // You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
  // object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this
  // won't work inside `oneOfType`.
  customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is specific to sending different types of properties down to a child component like a prop can be a string, number, object, array, function, etc. you can understand better if you look at the code given in my question that explains in detail and meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass some component also as props something like this:

```
   import Sample from './Sample'
    class A extends Component {
   render(){
      const propComponent = <Sample />
       return(
          <B component={propComponent} />
       );
     }
  }
```

You can do the same by passing it is children also:

```
import Sample from './Sample'
class A extends Component {
   render(){
       return(
          <B>
          <Sample/>
          </B>
       );
     }
  }
```

Comment: Ok can you please confirm the prop type of the component that you are sending as a prop to B component? I mean here propComponent —> const propComponent = <Sample />

Comment: yeah as per docs it should be node https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Any parameter that can be passed to a function can be passed to a react Component.

If you are asking what are the names (types) for each prop then you can check the [PropTypes library under the usage section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types#usage) that lists most (if not all) of them.